# Cannot bind operator << in cpp

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Guru,

Given two classes defined as follow (attributes, methods, and implementation omitted) :

```
struct A { friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& o, const A& c); };
struct B { friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& o, const B& c); };
```

I used the classes as follow:

```
ln 1: A *arrayA = new A[10];
ln 2: B *arrayB = new B[10];
ln 3: /* some codes to initialize arrayA and arrayB */
ln 4: for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { std::cout << arrayA[i]; } // this work 
ln 5: for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) { std::cout << arrayB[j]; } // this complain
```

My compiler complains for class B as

```
error: cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' lvalue 
to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'

../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/ostream:581:5 error initializing argument 1 
of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& 
std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) 
 [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Tp = ClsB]
```

I don't know what's wrong with line 5. Commenting out line 5 of the main program give my good compilation, meaning my definition of the operator<< for class B is syntactically correct. Please give any directions and thanks.

Yam Hon

- Platform: win 7
- MinGW32: version 2011-11-08
- GNU Make 3.82
- G++ version 4.6.1

[Edit 1]
My program actually has more than two classes, and all my class have operator<< overloaded for debugging. I used the same signature (with appropriate 2nd argument) for all classes. Only class B give this error.

[Edit 2]
full version of my classes:

```
struct CPeople { // this is class B
int age;
int ageGroup;

int zipcode;
int communityID;
int areaID;
int familyID;
int contactID;
int contactType; /* P, D, E, M, H, W */
int state;
int vaccinated; /* 0 = unvac, 1 = vaccinated */

friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, const CPeople& c)
{
    o << "CPeople (" << static_cast<void const *>(&c) << "): "
      << "\tAge Group: "   << c.ageGroup
      << "\tZip Code: "    << c.zipcode
      << "\tCommunityID: " << c.communityID
      << "\tArea ID: "     << c.areaID
      << "\tFamily ID: "   << c.familyID
      << "\tSchool Type: " << c.contactType
      << "\tContact ID: "  << c.contactID
      << "\tState: "       << c.state
      << "\tVaccination: " << c.vaccinated;
    return (o << std::endl);
}
};

struct CWorkGroup : public CContact { // this is class A
/* to which community this member belongs */
std::vector<long> member_com;
CStatistics statistics;

friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, const CWorkGroup& c)
{
    o << "CWorkGroup (" << static_cast<void const *>(&c) << "): ";
    o << "avflag = " << c.avflag << "; member: " << c.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++)
    {
        o << "; (" << i << " = " << c.member[i] << ")";
    }
    o << std::endl;
    return (o << c.statistics);
}
};
```

Usage A:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cntWG; i++) { std::clog << WG[i]; } std::clog << std::endl;
```

Usage B (this is error):

```
CPeople *people_total = new CPeople[cntTotalPop];
for (pIdx = 0; pIdx < cntTotalPop; pIdx++)
{
    std::cout << people_total[pIdx];
}
```

Comment: What does your function header for the implementation of `operator<<` (for B) look like?

Comment: Have you missed `;` at the end of class bodies ? Also you may post the  some relevant code appearing at line 3.

Comment: actually all operator<< are defined as friend and they are implemented inside the class definitions

Comment: I'd still like to see the definition of the `B` version. Check to make sure the `B` implementation has a parameter `std::ostream &` and not `std::ostream &&`.

Comment: does your `operator <<` for `class B` use `std::bind`?

Comment: There isn't enough information here to figure out what the problem is. Can you post a small example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Are you disabling any of the special member functions for `class B` (think of the copy ctor, assignment operator and destructor)?

Comment: All my classes have not user-defined ctor/destructor/operators. And for i'm not using `std:bind` in my program.

Answer (score 1):

Classes and structs need to end with a semicolon, so add a semicolon at the end of both lines:

```
struct A { friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& o, const A& c); };
struct B { friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& o, const B& c); };
```

Comment: @YamHon.CHAN, did that solve your problem? If not, are you getting the same error?

Comment: the missing comma is just typo. thanks for pointing out that. The same error still occurs